# Wind Tunnel Issues

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hello dear Blender users,
I'm pretty new to Blender and just wanna ask you for your support.

I tried to create a virtual Wind Tunnel, but I got some issues:

1. I don't have a solid stream of particles, but 2 tiny flows at left and right.
2. For simulation I used Fluids - hope air can be prescribed like that.

[image: my try]

How can I get proper wind tunnel options?

File is here: https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=4671e0eaa9

Regards